# How to Sort New Products at Home by Product Name

Tags: grid, home, new-products, product-sorting

how to sort New Products at Home by Product Name ?

[image]

because I see to put it through CMS page in the Admin:

Admin - CMS Pages - home - Content :

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="4" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New` in local folder or extend it with your own

Find the below function

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
            case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
                $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
                break;
            default:
                $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
                break;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

and replace with this

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
            case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
                $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
                break;
            default:
                $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
                break;
        }
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('name');
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Akhilesh. It works. And only my curiosity, to display only 4 or 5 product, through Home content in the admin simply set products_count with 4 or 5 -> `products_count="5"` or `products_count="4"`. Whether to sort (like sort by Product Name) also through the content in the admin?

Comment: This is not the right way of overriding a function, you're basically copying an entire class. Using `local` is a very ugly method, please follow this guide instead: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: I already ask to extend in my question

Answer (score 2):

**Please update bellow function from:**

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
            case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
                $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
                break;
            default:
                $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
                break;
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

**To**

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
        case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
            $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
           $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
            //or $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc'); 
            break;
        default:
            $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
            break;
    }
    return $collection;
```

Comment: Thank you Abdul. It works. And only my curiosity, to display only 4 or 5 product, through Home content in the admin simply set products_count with 4 or 5 -> `products_count="5"` or `products_count="4"`. Whether to sort (like sort by Product Name) also through the content in the admin?